# How to unite second level ManyToManyFields?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I have models as follows:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Element(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')

class Category(models.Model):
    elements = models.ManyToManyField('Element')

    @property
    def tags(self):
        ...  # how can I do this?
```

How can I get the union of all the tags that appear in elements of a given category?

I could do something like this:

```py
def tags(self):
    all_tags = Tag.objects.none()
    for element in self.elements.all():
        all_tags = all_tags | element.tags.all()
    return all_tags.distinct()
```

But is there a way to do this directly at database level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [double underscore notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) to traverse relations:

```
def tags(self):
    return Tag.objects.filter(element__category=self)
```